# Convert view into bitmap with modification

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

**Requirement** : User should be able to share the layout(which has image and text) as image.

**Solution which i tried:**

```
   Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
   myView.draw(c);
```

This is working as expected. But I have few issues.

**Issues**:
I have few buttons and text which i don't want to convert as image. Also,I want to add my App logo as a watermark on the Bitmap image.

**My solution for the above issue**:

- Before converting to Bitmap Image, Change visibility state of Button and Logo Image
- Create one more layout behind the actual layout in a sharable image format. Use this layout to get Bitmap Image  (not cool efficient, But easy way)

**My question:**
The above solutions are valid?
Or Is there any other method to do in an efficient way?

PS: I am not looking for code. :)

Comment: Please don't tag questions with IDE tags (`android-studio`) just because you use that IDE: these tags should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Firstly, the question is good structured, easy to read and understand. You have included your attempts also, which makes it a good question already, thanks for the work on your question. As for the answer: This is the way I'd do that, and I don't think that it worth to improve anything except *watermark*: I'd draw it on top of the screenshot taken

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thank you for your valuable input :) and i also i would continue posting question in similar format :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1: yes, you have to change visibility of those views you don't want them to be converted into image(the easiest way).

Issue 2: for adding a watermark, you can just draw it on canvas(you can use canvas.drawBitmap to do it) instead of putting it in the layout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would follow the easiest way. (changing visibility of views)